# implementing http for my payment controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using rails 3.2 and I would like my payment forms to redirect to https.

I tried the following in my routes.rb which didn't work:

```
resources :payments, only: [:new, :create], :constraints => { :protocol => "https" }
```

The error I receive is:

```
No route matches [GET] "/payments/new"
```

I am testing this in my local environment at the moment and it works fine without the `contraints`

Comment: Well man thanks for the question i forgot about https and will implement it into my project

Answer (score 1):

You want to redirect to the https version of the `payments/new` route, not put a constraint on it. This is why you're seeing the `No route` error (assuming you're not using https on localhost). Read up on doing what you want on [here](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/). Here's a neat Rack middleware gem you can use to do the redirect: https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl

Comment: Thanks for the link what confused me is that it says "Behind the scenes, Rails adds the awesome Rack::SSL Rack middleware to your application middleware stack" so I thought it meant it added it automatically and no gem was needed.

Comment: @Aryad yea I think it's included you just have to configure it so it know's which routes you want to be https only.

Comment: yeap just adding config.force_ssl = true without installing any gem seems to put https on all pages now I need to figure out how to filter it for just my route